# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastai.structured'

Tags: python, fast-ai

I was trying to create some features from date column using 'add_datepart' function from 'fastai.structured' module in 'fastai' library. I got this error:

```
from fastai.structured import add_datepart
```

After lot of googling, I found that 'structured' module was removed in 2018 update of fastai librabry. There are discussions around it but I could not find any solution for my problem. Is there any way to download old 'structured' module so that I can use add_datepart to create features from date column in my dataframe or is there any alternative solution to solve my problem? I have also tried to download old version of 'fastai' but installation of old version also failed:

```
!pip install fastai==0.7.0
```

Comment: I'm not aware of this module, but lookup through the project's source gave me this https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/99d38fec7207db9b4209568bebc85ded7e3d3f1b/fastai/tabular/core.py#L24

Comment: Thank you @kozlone. After going through your link, I found solution to my problem. I'll post soon how I actually got rid of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to this problem. 'structured' module in 'fastai' has been replaced with 'core' module inside 'tabular' folder in 'fastai' library. So instead of importing 'add_datepart' from 'structured' module import it from 'core'. In short we need to make following changes in our code:

Replace this code-

```
from fastai.structured import add_datepart
```

with following code-

```
from fastai.tabular.core import add_datepart
```

Rest all will remain unchanged. Tricky but a very simple solution. I hope this helps many other coders since I saw many coders struggling with this issue and asking for solution.